# Resize components when the window resize

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I need to resize components when the user resizes the window.

I think this is very easy with `GridBagLayout`, using the weight properties and fill property to both.

However, I was wondering can I do the same in other layouts?

Does anybody know a way to resize components in all layouts?

Comment: It is obviously very layout specific. Some layouts don't change the size of components on window resize.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556) for two very easy ways to stretch a component to fill the size of the parent container (using `BorderLayout` & `GridLayout`).

Comment: How components are sized (or not) is a feature (in fact, **the** primary feature) of any given layout manager. Read the docs for the layouts to find out which does what.

Answer (score 1):

You might compare the two contrasting examples shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14587999/230513). Both make the size of two flanking borders proportional to the central panel.

- The [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14588568/230513), uses `GridBagLayout`.
- The [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14588506/230513) uses a `ComponentListener`.