# How to make JFreeChart to keep aspect ratio?

Tags: java, jfreechart, aspect-ratio

Is it possible to keep some aspect ratio of units? For example, is it possible to make them square?

In the following example a rectangle draw. Unfortunately, it is possible to make it square by resizing window. Is it possible to tell JFreeChart to keep ratio while resizing?

```
package tests.org.jfree.chart;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.xy.DefaultXYDataset;

public class Runner_JFreeChart_01 {

    public static class MyChartPanel extends ChartPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8474384653351996554L;

        DefaultXYDataset dataset = new DefaultXYDataset();
        {
            dataset.addSeries("key", new double[][]{{10, 300, 300, 10, 10},{10, 10, 50, 50, 10}});
        }

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("", "", "", dataset);

        public MyChartPanel() {
            super(null);
            setChart(chart);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Runner_JFreeChart_01");
                frame.add(new MyChartPanel());

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });


    }

}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a `ComponentListener`?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't want to prevent component from resize. I would like a chart keeping ratio withing resizing component.

Comment: Probably more like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14588506/230513).

Answer (score 1):

In your main try adding the following code and see if it works.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
     MyChartPanel myChart = new MyChartPanel();
     myChart.setMinimumDrawWidth(0);
     myChart.setMaximumDrawWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
     myChart.setMinimumDrawHeight(0);
     myChart.setMaximumDrawHeight(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

      // Other code here
```

Then where you add your chart to the JFrame:
replace the following code:

```
frame.add(new MyChartPanel());
```

with

```
frame.add(myChart);
```

Enjoy!